# JAVASCRIPT - checking for the first letter to be A-Z

Tags: javascript

**I'm trying to write a code to check for a valid username. What have I done wrong? If I enter my username and it starts with a-z, it says that it is not valid.
Also, I cannot use regex expressions.**

```
var BR = "<br />";
var username = "";
var letter1;
var digit; 
letter1 = username.substr(0,1);

username = prompt("Please enter a your username:");

//First letter begin with a letter
if (letter1 >= "a" && letter1 <= "z") {
document.write("The first character is valid." + BR);
}
else {
document.write("The first character is not valid." + BR);
}
```

**Thanks for the help!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put letter1 = username.substr(1, 2) statement **AFTER** you read the username from line
username = prompt("Please enter a your username:");

You should get the first letter of the username after the username is popluated by the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Dilip/2t9n6vpt/1/

```
var BR = "<br />";
var username = "";
var letter1;
var digit; 
letter1 = username.substr(0,1);

username = prompt("Please enter a your username:");

//First letter begin with a letter
var aCode = 'a'.charCodeAt(0);
var zCode = 'z'.charCodeAt(0);
if (username.charCodeAt(0) >= aCode && username.charCodeAt(0) <= zCode) {
document.write("The first character is valid." + BR);
}
else {
document.write("The first character is not valid." + BR);
}
```

> username.charCodeAt(0)

Will give ASCII value of the first character.  You can check using this.

Comment: It's really bad style to hard-code ASCII character codes. Do something like `var aCode = "a".charCodeAt(0);`

Answer (score 0):

Switch the order of your "letter1 =" and "username =" statements.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your letter to ascii and then check like this: https://jsfiddle.net/pyexm7us/2/

I also made it check for uppercase letters too:

Javascript

```
var BR = "<br />";
var username = ""; 
var digit; 


username = prompt("Please enter a your username:");
var ascii = username.charCodeAt(0);

//First letter begin with a letter
if (ascii >= 97 && ascii <= 122 || ascii >= 65 && ascii <= 90) {
document.write("The first character is valid." + BR);
}
else {
document.write("The first character is not valid." + BR);
}
```